# Spring boot - rest controller access only for another MS in the same discovery using feign

Tags: java, spring-boot, api-gateway, spring-cloud-feign, service-discovery

Using spring boot and microservices, that using discovery, gateway, feign and many microservices. What I'm searching is a way that in the same MS, I have rest api controller that can be access from a call that pass for the gateway, and have rest api controller that only can be called from MS that is present in the same discovery, that can't be called from the gateway. I try to search for this, but not have success.

1. I expecting to find the solution or where I can find some anwer that I can search with have a chance to resolve my problem.